# Accessing printQueue class from Windows Form1

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have an array of objects would int and string and i want to output it in a listbox in the form. The array of objects is in another class Item

Is it possible just to make the Form1 recognise in the Class Item like this

Or do i have to send the result back to form1 and input it into the listbox there?

> Class Item

```
 public void printPQ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++)
        {
            //contents += (items.elements[i] == null ? null : items.elements[i].name) + "\n"; 
            lblShowPatient.Text = (items.elements[i].priority + items.elements[i].name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your `Form1` as a constructor to your `class` (since I don't see a name, we'll call it `ClassA`) such that you have a constructor of the following signature:

```
public Form1 Form1 {get;set;}

public ClassA(Form1 form1)
{
    Form1 = form1;
}
```

Then, when initializing your `ClassA` instance from `Form1`, you'll call it like this:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA(this); //Where this is the current instance of Form1
```

This would allow you to access elements of an instance of `Form1` from within your class.

However, this seems a little upside down from how you'd really want to write it. I'd recommend refactoring `ClassA`'s `printPQ` to instead be named `ExportPQ` and return a `List<string>`. Then in your `Form1` logic that calls the method, iterate through what's returned from `ClassA.ExportPQ` and fill in the `ListBox`. This allows your `ClassA` to be more useful as you now have a method to return this information in a multitude of UI controls and not just this specific `ListBox` on `Form1`.

Comment: That works i can access ClassA in Form1 but i would like to do it the other way around access Form1 in ClassA

Comment: Everything written before "However," would allow you to access `Form1` in `ClassA`. How are you currently instantiating `ClassA` form `Form1` and calling `printPQ()`?